# Design pattern term for "couplers"?

Tags: design-patterns

Lots of discussions online about software patterns for coupling modules (e.g., [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))). I've written modules that interface different modules, including adapters, interfaces, and message parsers. My question is, could these be collectively called "couplers"? I ask because I'm putting together a presentation and "coupler" doesn't appear to have been adopted by developers as a description of modules dedicated to passing information between other modules. What is the accepted term for dedicated coupling modules?

Comment: Coupling is a _negative_ characteristic of software. The goal of good software patterns is to achieve low coupling and high cohesion. In other words, patterns aim to _decouple_ modules from each other.

Comment: @jaco0646, thanks for the thoughts. Coupling simply means to connect two or more things. Coupling is a problem only when there is too much of it. Regardless, what would you collectively call patterns that connect modules?

Comment: Communication between modules should generally be achieved via messaging; but this is describing software at a very abstract level, and the term _module_ can be language dependent.